# Why doesn't SVN client offer option to accept certificate if run from Cygwin?

Tags: svn, cygwin, visualsvn-server

I'm writing instructions for setting up a new Windows 2008 R2 build server which needs to access a VisualSVN Server repository that has a self-signed certificate.

I've installed TortoiseSVN with the option to add the command line tools and if I run the command `svn list https://...` in a Windows command prompt, I get the usual "Error validating server certificate for https://..." message, and the option to "(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently?"

If I run the same command in a Cygwin Terminal, however (even one run as Administrator), I just get two E230001 error messages:

```
svn: E230001: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://...'
svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted
```

i.e. as if I'd selected "(R)eject" when running in the command prompt.

`which svn` is reporting that Cygwin is running from `/cygdrive/c/Program Files/TortoiseSVN/bin/svn` so it looks to me like it's the same executable both times.

Does anyone know how to get round this? All the instructions I've written so far can be carried out within a single Cygwin Terminal session; I'd like not to complicate things by having to say "before continuing, switch to a Windows command prompt just to accept the SVN server cert", if possible!

Comment: that is odd. you can get around it with svn list --non-interactive and --trust-server-cert  However as soon as you need interaction, for example a commit without supplying a message, it won't work.

Comment: Quite. And once the server is set up, the people using it aren't going to be developer types. They can be given simple instructions, such as "type 'svn up' then type 'make all'", but the longer the command line, the more chance I'm going to have to deal with the consequences of finger trouble!

Comment: Quick note: adding --non-interactive --trust-server-cert doesn't get you past a problem if you specify the "wrong" hostname (e.g. if certificate uses the server's FQDN and you're using just the hostname, or vice versa), and of course it doesn't update the accepted certificates data, so you have to type it in every time :-(